# Issue with running over two parallel executions with Karate

Tags: karate

Edit: I can understand the comment from the redirected post "Sorry, running browser tests in parallel is non-trivial which is why we have the Docker option."

Please correct me if am wrong here, my understanding is that the parallel execution provided with Karate UI is for running tests in parallel on individual browser.

I am getting the following error messages when trying to run more than 2 parallels.

Would appreciate if I could get some guidance on this.

11:28:18.286 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:54112 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect, http call failed after 4008 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:54112/json

11:28:20.919 [chrome_1627381645623] WARN  com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 1 - [C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=C:\Users\Projects\target\chrome_1627381645623, --disable-popup-blocking] working dir: target\chrome_1627381645623

11:28:24.307 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:54112 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect, http call failed after 4019 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:54112/json

11:28:30.313 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:54112 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect, http call failed after 4005 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:54112/json

11:31:24.955 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - driver config / start failed: http call failed after 4031 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:54112/json, options: {type=chrome, showDriverLog=true, target=null}
com.intuit.karate.KarateException: http call failed after 4031 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:54112/json